External download is Disabled_TestNG eclipse
!download External resource is disabled](https://i.sstatic.net/V6rFKVth.png)
I am not getting how to resolve the issue.
I tried to modifued the Network connecting setting as Direct in eclipse but its not resolving the issue in TestNG XML
I tried to download TestNG tdt file in local and kept in project loactio and tried but still its throwing same error in TestNG File.Please look into above screenshot and let me know the solution.
Expected Result:
Let me know How to resolve this error.
